# Google App Engine: Create a 'Save as draft' feature for an entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, webapp2

I would like to create a 'save as draft' feature for a long entity form.

Consider the data structure example below:

```
class BigEntity(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    # Many more properties ...
```

The form.html:

```
<form method="post">
    Title: <input type="text" name="title">
    <!-- Very long form -->
    Submit <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    Save As Draft <input type="submit" value="Save As Draft">
</form>
```

What is a solid way to build a 'save as draft' feature for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a property isDraft to your entity and set it to true or false depending on which button was pressed.

Comment: thank you for answering. This seems to be a viable solution. However, how would the assigned handler know which button is pressed?

Comment: You can assign a different handler to each button, or you can check the source of a native browser event if you use one handler.

Comment: Hmm, how might a separate handler be assigned to each button? As far as I know, each form should be allowed one 'submit' button, right? So how might we assign two handlers to two separate submit buttons in a single form?